# Object literal with single identifier inside

Tags: javascript

I recently came across code like this:

```
if (!validate(event)) {
    logger.error('Invalid message: validation failed', { event })
}
```

which got me wondering, what's it called when you enclose an object in an object literal like `{ event }`, which appears to just give you a new object that looks like:

```
let event = { "a": 1, "b": 2 }

console.log({ event })
// { event: { a: 1, b: 2 } }
```

Why does this work this way / what is it called?

Comment: answer was: "shorthand property names"

Answer (score -1):

It is called object construction - as appose to [object deconstruction](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/)